# Automatically populate relationship index in Neo4J 3.x?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

In Neo4J 2.x there was a special option in conf settings to automatically index certain relationship properties.

But how to do it in 3.x? Can it automatically populate relationship index and which APOC function could be used for that? I can't find it in the manual...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [triggers](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_triggers). For example trigger for created relationship:

```
CALL apoc.trigger.add(
 'relsIndexUpdateCreatedRelationships',
 'UNWIND {createdRelationships} as rel
  CALL apoc.index.addRelationship(rel, ["user"])
  RETURN count(rel)
 ',
 {phase: 'after'}
)
```

And of course you need to handle these triggers too: `deletedRelationships`, `removedRelationshipProperties`, `assignedRelationshipProperties`.